# The probability P[X < g(Y)]

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous random
variables having densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$ , respectively. What is the probability of $P[X < g(Y)]$ being $g(\cdot)$ a continous functions?

Comment: I believe this problem is best solved using cumulative distributions, but I don't remember exactly how $g$ would transform $F_Y$. Someone should get on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every independent $(X,Z)$ with $X$ continuous, $P[X\lt Z\mid Z=z]=P[X\lt z]=F_X(z)$, hence
$$
P[X\lt Z]=E[F_X(Z)].
$$
Apply this to $Z=g(Y)$. Neither $Y$ nor $g$ is required to be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are independent then the joint pdf will look like $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. Then we can perform the transoformation or variables from $Y$ to $Z=g(Y)$: $f_{XZ}(x,z)=f_X(x)f_Z(z)\left|\frac{\partial g(y)}{\partial y}\right|$. The question $P[X < g(Y)]$ prompts us to use the joint cdf of $X$ and $Z$: $F_{XZ}(x,z)$. 

So $P[X < Z]=F_X(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}F_{XZ}(z,z')\mathrm dz'$.

Comment: Note that P[X<Z] is a number and that your answer makes it a function of a mysterious variable z.

Comment: @Did What's wrong with cdf? $P[X < Z]=F_X(z)=F_X(x=g(y))$ meaning the cdf of $X$, evaluated at the point $g(y)$. It is a number. And why is $z$ _mysterious_? Just a short hand notation, in order not to carry $g(y)$ everywhere.

Comment: If $P[X\lt Z]=F_X(z)$, then $z$ is a real number. Which one is it? $z=0$? $z=42$? $z=\frac12\pi$?